# How to cache tiles on my server for a leaflet app

Tags: caching, leaflet, webserver

I am building a web app based on leaflet using tiles from third parties maps with CC license and, as per request by tiles owners, I would like to cache them on my server.

My leaflet app is calling to tiles located on, for example, https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png. So the question is, how can I cache the tiles on my web server? Is there a leaflet functionallity for that or should I call to [https://tiles.myserver.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://tiles.myserver.com/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png) and, somehow, write the logic to return that file or download and cache the original tile from the source url? If this was the case, could you please give me some guideline? (Apache directive, php... I can investigate whatever needed but don't know where to start looking at).

Thanks!

Comment: See https://mapproxy.org/

Comment: I can see that I won't reinvent the wheel. Mapproxy seems to do exactly what I want (and probably more), however it requires Python and installing something on server... Is it the only solution or are there any other alternatives over there, hopefully not needing additional installations on the server? Thanks!

Comment: Of course I can investigate whatever, but before further investigating Mapproxy I would like to know if there are other alternatives to choose the one that best fits my needs.